# set baud speed for tty

Tags: tty, devices, serial-port, iphone

How do I set the baud speed for a specific tty (in this case a serial port)? I tried using

```
stty -F /dev/tty.iap ispeed 19200
```

But get the error `Invalid argument` for every speed I try (2400, 4800, etc.) except 9600 (the default). I can successfully change the speed in a C program using `cfsetspeed`. Do I need to make a change somewhere else, like the `ttys` file?

Comment: Why the iphone tag? are you really using iPhone?

Comment: well actually a jailbroken ipod touch, basically the same. (iap is ipod access protocol.) I figured this question would fit here better than the apple stackexchange site. It is a Unix/Linux question, have the same problem on my mac.

Comment: Try just leaving out the "ispeed" word.

Comment: @Keith, then I don't get an error message, but I run `stty -F /dev/tty.iap` to get details, it still says `speed 9600 baud;`.

Comment: 1) «I can successfully change the speed in a C program using cfsetspeed» — have you verified it with `stty` then? 2) «like the ttys file?» ­— what `ttys` file exactly? :)

Comment: @poige: 1) the verification was for me that i was able to recognize the input coming to on that port ;) 2) doesn't the `/private/etc/ttys` file store the settings for `stty`?

Comment: @newenglander, well, I'd have verified that with `stty` itself — it could pour some light upon… 2) I dunno where `/private` corresponds to, but `/etc/ttys` is BSD-flavor's [thing][1] with SysV [counterpart /etc/inittab][2] (to some extent).


  [1]: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ttys&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html
  [2]: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=inittab&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=SuSE%20Linux/i386%2011.3&arch=default&format=html

Answer (score 51):

I use the command `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600`.

Comment: Perfect. Now I can echo commands out over serial, at the correct baud rate, as follows: `echo -ne 'my message to send over serial\n' > /dev/ttyUSB0`

Answer (score 7):

I use screen for this purpose

`# screen /dev/ttyUSB0 38400`

works like a charm

Comment: I think the goal here is to set the baud rate for the device so you can then echo commands straight over serial. Ex: `echo -ne 'my message to send over serial\n' > /dev/ttyUSB0`. I think **screen** is great too, but @Kotte has the correct answer on how to do what is being asked.

Comment: Yes, Kotte has correct answer for the question. Still often the problem is not just in baud rate, but also in other parameters. In my case setting baud rate with `stty` was not enough, but `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200` has automagically configured all parameters and it just worked.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a permissions issue.

/dev/ttyUSB0 is an IO port, to avoid using sudo or root you should add your user to the group which owns the device. You can check that with, e.g.

```
$ ls /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Mar 29 09:12 /dev/ttyS0
```

To edit the file:

```
sudo vipw -g
```

the file will look like this:

[image]

look for dialout group and add you username at the end, then logout/login from your session or reboot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On my machine, neither `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600` or `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600` worked for me, but `sudo stty speed 9600` was successful.

Comment: This only works if you are logged into the TTY you're trying to modify.