# Running picocom in the background without open session

Tags: background-process, serial-port, terminal-emulator, nohup, jobs

I would like picocom to log serial data on a remote computer, without having to keep my ssh session to the remote computer alive.

I have tried:

---

```
picocom <my options>
```

This dies when I logout.

---

```
picocom <my options> &
```

No output on terminal, and exiting `picocom` with `C-a C-x` leaves the job as stopped, it doesn't kill it (I need to `kill -9`, a simple `kill` on the job does not work. I then have to manually clean the tty lock in `/var/lock/`).

---

```
picocom <my options> > tmp/data.log&
```

then in another ssh session:

```
tail -f tmp/data.log
```

No data cames out in the file `data.log`.

---

```
bash -c "picocom --baud 115200 /dev/ttyACM1 > /home/pi/tmp/data.log" &
```

No output to the file either. The job becomes "Stopped" right away.

---

```
nohup sh -c "picocom --baud 115200 /dev/ttyACM1 > /home/pi/tmp/data.log" &
```

I get the start output of `picocom` in the tailed file, but then the job is exited.

---

Good to know as well: `picocom` does not react to `C-z`.

My questions are:

- is it at all possible to run `picocom` in the background?
- what alternatives are there to log serial terminal without an open session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is to [setup the device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57629/38106) with `stty`, then [read it with cat](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/background-logging-of-dev-ttys0-output-627365/):

```
stty <my options>
nohup sh -c "cat /dev/ttyACM0 > data.log" &
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [dtach](https://github.com/crigler/dtach). dtach allows you to run programs in the background. I have been successfully using it with picocom to do serial logging without an open session (on a remote Raspberry Pi).

I also recommend using picocom's built-in logging `-g` to save serial data to a file.

Once you have dtach installed, you can run it with picocom like;

`dtach -A /tmp/dtach picocom --baud 115200 /dev/ttyACM1 -g /home/pi/tmp/data.log`

then once picocom is running, you can put it in the background with `C-\`

to rejoin the "dtached" process use;

`dtach -a /tmp/dtach`

I have found that picocom does write to the log file in the background, so I can `cat /home/pi/tmp/data.log` with picocom still running but "dtached"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user session is meant, you might be able to use `screen` with  the `-X` option to send commands to a running screen session and the `stuff` command to send keystrokes to the current window.

```
screen -dmS newScreen bash
screen -S newScreen -X stuff "picocom <options>\n"
screen -ls
screen -r <pid>
```

Please take note to put the quotes around and the next line in order for the commands to be executed. [*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7049314/6771046)

... haven't checked if `bash -c` or `tmux` would be possible too.